# OpenStreetMap OSMXML not rendering

Tags: javascript, maps, render, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am trying to offline-render a part of OpenStreetMap, previously loaded as map.osm (OSM XML). I'm starting a localhost and loading the xml from disk.

I tried to use similar example (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-osm.html) changing only the source to my file, yet this didn't work out. Data loaded is pretty much similar to data I see in the example.

I tried a bunch of various approaches, and I still can't render the map. I get no errors, and I can't get what I'm missing.

```
var vectorSource = new VectorSource({
   format: new OSMXML()
 });

 var xml = await fetch('map.osm').then(res => res.text());

 var features = (new OSMXML()).readFeatures(xml);
 // Features are parsed OK
 vectorSource.addFeatures(features);

 var vector = new VectorLayer({
   source: vectorSource,
   // Using styles, I don't post them here (a lot of code)
   style: function (feature) {
     for (var key in styles) {
       var value = feature.get(key);
       if (value !== undefined) {
         for (var regexp in styles[key]) {
           if (new RegExp(regexp).test(value)) {
             return styles[key][regexp];
           }
         }
       }
     }
     return null;
   }
 });
 map = new Map({
   layers: [vector],
   target: document.getElementById('map'),
   view: new View({
     center: [0, 0],
     maxZoom: 0,
     zoom: 0
   })
 });
```

Comment: did you get it to work? i have the same problem